# nodeJS spawn child_process doesn't work on glitch.com

Tags: javascript, node.js, hosting, spawn, enoent

I want to serve an express server on glitch.com with the following code:

```
const path = require('path');
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));

const defaultServerPath = path.join(__dirname, 'default/index.js');
const defaultServerProcess = spawn('node', [defaultServerPath], { env: { PORT: 4000 } });

defaultServerProcess.on('exit', (code) => {
  console.log(`Der erste Server wurde mit dem Code ${code} beendet!`);
});

const roomServerPath = path.join(__dirname, 'room/index.js');
const roomServerProcess = spawn('node', [roomServerPath], { env: { PORT: 5000 } });

roomServerProcess.on('exit', (code) => {
  console.log(`Der zweite Server wurde mit dem Code ${code} beendet!`);
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Reverse proxy server running on ${port}`);
});
```

It works locally by running the script with node index.js or npm run start but not on glitch.

I get this error message on https://glitch.com/.
app@indigo-midi-sushi:~ 08:54
$ npm run start

```
> express-socket_chatroom@1.0.0 start /app
> nodemon index.js

[nodemon] 2.0.22
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn node ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I know that the spawning of the processes causes the error, but why?
spawn('node', [], { env: { PORT:  }

Comment: As a first step, you probably want to use `exec` rather than `spawn`, which should at least tell you which command it's trying to run that's triggering the ENOENT.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I get 
[nodemon] 2.0.22
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Reverse proxy server running on 3000
Der erste Server wurde mit dem Code 127 beendet!
Der zweite Server wurde mit dem Code 127 beendet! 
with exec.

But the files exist.

Comment: right, but as you can see, exec is telling you that something is exiting with code 127, so unless you wrote code do that, that's not _your_ code doing the exiting it looks like. Time to find out whether `nodemon` has conditions under which it generates code 127, or whether any of your dependencies do. That said, running exec/spawn on Glitch is tricky to begin with: Glitch apps go to sleep and can get cycled, so you generally don't want something that relies on nodemon or pm2 or the like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you cannot expose more than one port on glitch.